# Classic ASP Send Mail To E-Mail Address Inputted In Textbox

Tags: session, asp-classic, textbox, cdo.message

I am trying to receive an input for an e-mail address from a textbox in one .asp file called order.asp and then e-mail to that e-mail address using code in another .asp file called ordercomplete.asp (which uses CDO mail). The mailer works correctly if i specifically define ObjSendMail.To = someemail@provider.com, but not if i use a session variable such that ObjSendMail.To = Session("EmailSession") so that it's more dynamic. This is order.asp

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="ordercomplete.asp">
  <p>
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <%
    Session("EmailSession") = Request.Form("email")
    %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-Mail Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

In ordercomplete.asp, I tried to see if I can print the value that's been inputted in the email textbox in order.asp before I can go ahead and set ObjSentMail.To to the session variable. I tried to print and see if there is anything saved in Session("EmailSession")) at all using

```
<%
Response.Write(Session("EmailSession"))
%>
```

but it prints nothing. How can I get an inputted value from one asp file to transfer in this manner in another asp file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your inputs for AspNet textboxes. Change your input button for an AspNet button. Add a handler for the OnClick event. There, explicitly add the email from the textbox to the session object. The following code is not tested, so check it before using

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session.Add(txtEmail.Text);
    Response.Redirect("~/MyOtherPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I am a newbie at ASP and ASP.NET. Is there a way that I can keep .asp instead of using ASP.NET and .aspx and does it make a difference?

Comment: Forgive me , I though you were in Asp.Net instead of classic Asp.However, if you're learning a new language, why start with such and old thing as classics Asp? ;-)

Comment: I know, it's irritating, the organization that I was doing it for wanted it as Classic ASP. I finally convinced them to change it to ASP.NET and now the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are posting the form in `order.asp` to `ordercomplete.asp`. The form field `email` will only be available in the posted-to page, which you have given as `ordercomplete.asp` in the form action: `action="ordercomplete.asp"`

In `ordercomplete.asp`, you can get the value of the form field using `Request.Form("email")` .